# Getting "The column name xxx is not valid" exception when trying to combine columns

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, jdbc

I am trying to combine two columns in SQL query but getting the following exception in java.sql.ResultSet's FindColumn method:

> JdbcSqlException: The column name
>   FullName is not valid. Column:
>   'FullName'

Here is my SQL query

```
SELECT U.FirstName + ' ' + U.LastName AS FullName FROM User as U
```

Anyone?

Please note that query runs fine when I run it directly in SQL Server management studio. Also, this query is part of a big query that's why U as alias.

Comment: are you able to post the full query? I get the feeling the problem is not in this SELECT.

Comment: Sorry, my bad. It was a mistake in my code. Nothing to do with the query. Going to delete the question. @p.campbell. You were right. Thanks.

Comment: perhaps don't delete the question, but leave your findings for others. You won't be the first person to come across this problem.

Comment: @p.campbell. Yeah, you are right. Not deleting it. Though hope people don't downvote it :)

Comment: You should post an answer explaining the root cause and then mark it accepted when time allows it.

Answer (score 1):

When you put "AS FullName", Fullname is a label now. JDBC gets data by "column name" or "field name". You have to change your code (I dont know your prog. language) accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

You might try putting parentheses around the string concatenation, as in

```
SELECT (U.FirstName + ' ' + U.LastName) AS FullName FROM User U
```

Share and enjoy.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I am answering this late. I am sure someone will need the answer. I have had the same problem and whereas I do not know exactly why and what causes it, I have found a way to fix it (at least for my case).

jahanzeb farooq did not show his code but if you had declared the `PreparedStatement` and `ResultSet` variables variables outside the current method and used them in other queries then try declaring them anew inside the current method, that is

```
PreparedStatement pst=conn.prepareStetement(sql);
ResultSet rs=pst.executeQuery();
```

The problem will be sorted (or at least fixed)

Answer (score 0):

```
String sql = "SELECT U.FirstName + ' ' + U.LastName AS FullName FROM User U ";

pst = conn.prepareStatement(sql);

rs = pst.executeQuery();

if (rs.next()) {

  String fullname = rs.getString("FullName");

  jtextfiel.setText(fullname);

  //////or - short 

  jtextfiel.setText(rs.getString("FullName"));
}
```

Comment: Where is the description? Please add related description regarding your answer.  Avoid dumping just a code here. It is better if you have added some detail regarding your answer.

Comment: What is the problem you're encountering?